# how to add view to random position so that i can swipe to left and right direction of View Pager?

Tags: android, swipe, android-viewpager

My scenario is, 
 I Have List View with many data . and when user click on it. it navigate to detail page where  View pager is implemented.When user click on 10th item of List view it navigate to detail page but problem is "i am unable to swipe left though i have 9 item previously???"

```
if (collection != null) {
        view = (MyCustomScrollview) ((Activity) ctx).getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(layoutId, null);
        ((ViewGroup) collection).addView(view,0);
        holder = new ViewHolder(collection);
        collection.setTag(holder);

    }
```

here view is always added to 0th position. how can i add view to selected position???
Note :when i replace 0 with selected position of listview. compiler throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=2 count=0 ???

Comment: After some experiment i found the method setCurrentItem(index)that set the view to respective index of viewpager and i can swipe left too. but againa problem is "suppose if i currently @ 7th position and when i swipe left it shud show me the view with 6th position object info that has been set in pageadapter